# the user exists in the database into the Get_Id

Tags: php, mysqli

This is how I'm going to make a small sign system, it is such that it must find out if username is in the Get_id that you have visited,

GET_Id it is the page ID as it is for example 1 or 10

tilmeldt_navn the user's name on the page.

tilmeldt_email the person's own email.

I think like here in this still:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT tilmeldt_navn, tilmeldt_email FROM `tilmeldtOpgave` WHERE `get_id` = ?')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($tilmeldt_navn, $tilmeldt_email);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if($tilmeldt_navn == "")
            {
                echo "finds in the database";

            }
            else
            {
                echo "The finds in the database so can not sign me again!";    
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

the problem is: it does not appear in the with some of them at all.

The need to find out whether the user has signed up for the get_id and if it has it must take the last of if and when it does not have to be the roof the first in the if

Comment: We understand that not everyone speaks English, but could you try to reedit your question to be more clear. It is hard to follow what you are asking.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Google "Translate". It can't express what a person truly "feels".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's really hard to understand what you really want to happen. But, since you try to

*echo "finds in the database"* it seems that you want to check if the record exist from your database. 
Just try this:

```
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT tilmeldt_navn, tilmeldt_email FROM `tilmeldtOpgave` WHERE `get_id` = ?");
    $id= $_GET['id'];

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //Check if value is returned
        {
            while($stmt->fetch()) //To fetch the contents of the row
              {
                 echo 'Result Found';
              }
        }
        else {
            echo 'No result found';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt->free_result();
    }

      $mysqli->close();
      ?>
```

Hope this helps.